# My Completion Handler for a Swift App Doesn't Seem to Work

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a method found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/converting_between_coordinates_and_user-friendly_place_names) to convert a street address to coordinate points. My completion handler, when successful, should add the coordinate points to a list that I've initialized, but when I go into debug mode, the completion handler is ignored completely causing an Index Out Of Range Error. I think I'm doing something wrong with my completion handler which can be found below:

```
func setUp() {
    for a in addresses {
        print(a)
        getCoordinate(address: a, completionHandler: {coord , error in
            
            if error == nil {
            items.append(Location(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coord.latitude, longitude: coord.longitude), address: a))
                print("resulting coordinate = (\(coord.latitude),\(coord.longitude))")
            
            } else {
                print(error as Any)
            }
            
        })
        
    }
        
}
```

So to summarize, when I go to debug this problem, the debugger gets to line 4 in the snippet and then skips over the rest of the function. Thanks for any help!

Comment: as your code is async its will enter to completion when get response from the remote service.

Comment: Note that since you're making multiple async calls in a loop, there is no way to tell the order in which they will complete. You will not get the items back in the same order in which you make the requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how async code works. You make the call, and pass it a completion handler. The function call returns immediately. At some future date, the aysnc function finishes its work, and then it calls your completion handler.

Think of it like asking your kid to run to the store to buy some ingredients you need to finish making dinner. You give your kid the list send them on their way, and then go back to cooking the rest of dinner. When they come back, after an unpredictable delay, they tell you they have the stuff (call your completion handler) and at that point you take the items they gave you (Your completion handler can take parameters from the async function.)

If you set a breakpoint inside the completion handler, on the function call, and after the function call, you'll see the debugger first hit the function call, then the after-function-call breakpoint, and then at some future time you'll see it hit the completion handler code's breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you suggesting that the completion handler hasn't been fired yet and so my code is running into an error since the completion handler can't fill in the list called "items"?

Comment: You didn't talk about an error in enough detail for us to help with it. You talked about not hitting a breakpoint in your completion handler before exiting the function, which is expected for an async function call. You will have to tell us more about how you're trying to use `items`, and the error you're getting, if you want help debugging the error. What line is giving the error?

Comment: Hey, I was able to figure out the issue with your help. The problem was my completion handler wasn't triggered until it was too late, so I changed the logic in my code. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: That is what I was telling you. Completion handlers to async functions don't run until after the call to the async method has returned.

Comment: In case you run into a similar problem: You can add a breakpoint inside the handler and it will stop there when it executes (later). [just add it to the left of the line: "if error == nil {"]